# SO Roadmap and feature selection

Tags: discussion, meta

This is a question for the dev team, mainly.

What's the current process for deciding what to work on next? Do you internally use an issue tracker or just use meta?

Also, and more importantly, are there plans on having a public roadmap in the site?

Comment: Interesting, I was just looking at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=status-planned&sort=votes earlier today and wondering how some of these were progressing...

Comment: The results of the process, but not the process itself: [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange)

Answer (score 3):

***6-8 weeks***

Comment: Always an appropriate answer.